# Python3.4 Yahoo-Finance and matplotlib interferences

Tags: python, matplotlib, yahoo-finance, strptime

I'm very new to python programing, so i'm just starting to experiment.

Basically, i'm trying to request market data by using the Yahoo-Finance library and plot it with matplotlib.

Here is the code I use:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

from yahoo_finance import Share 
from datetime  import datetime, date, timedelta
#from matplotlib  import pyplot as plt

stm = Share("GOOG")
durée = timedelta(days=10)

lst = stm.get_historical(str(date.today()-durée), str(date.today()))

jours = [f['Date']for f in lst]
cours = [f['Open']for f in lst]

print(jours)
print(cours)

#plt.plot(jours, cours)
#plt.show()
```

When executed this way, the lists 'jours' and 'cours' are well printed. 
If I uncomment the ploting part of the code, I get an error on:

```
stm = Share("GOOG")
```

in the module _strptime.py : unconverted data remains: pm

I'm disappointed because it happens in a part of the code that was working before....

I thought it could be some kind of interference between library calls on different modules, but I don't know enough of python to debug it myself.

Any ideas about that?